# Why does flexboxgrid have media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries, flexbox

I am reading the source code of [flexboxgrid](https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid/blob/master/src/css/flexboxgrid.css) where I happened to notice that.

The common styles for `col-xs`, `col-sm` and `col-lg` are the same:

```
.col-xs,
.col-xs-1
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

The style for each `.col-[gridSize]-[columnSize]` does not vary as long as we only change `gridSize`:

```
.col-xs-1 {
  flex-basis: 8.33333333%;
  max-width: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-md-1 {
  flex-basis: 8.33333333%;
  max-width: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-lg-1 {
  flex-basis: 8.33333333%;
  max-width: 8.33333333%;
}
```

Similarly for `.col-[gridSize]-offset-[offsetNum]` looks like:

```
.col-xs-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-md-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-lg-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}
```

The only difference is that `xs` is not wrapped in media queries and `sm` and `md` are wrapped in `media queries`. I am converting this library into [css-in-js](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/flexboxgrid/blob/master/app/index.js), if the css is the same why wrap it in media queries?

Comment: I have not read that much about flexboxgrid, but most probably `xs` is not in a media query because it might be a mobile first framework, just like Bootstrap. The general idea is that you make your design based on how it looks on mobile then start building around that (that's why it's called **mobile first**)..  not the other way around, desktop to mobile.

Comment: I don't feel this needs an answer, you can look into [**mobile first**](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/35317) and if you have any doubts, we're here to help.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz I read that `%` elements work based off the parent's width which would either be container fluid which takes up the entire width if the screen or container which is defined in `rem`. Can you tell me a little bit more about how `.col-sm-1` interacts with `.container` whose width is fixed using media query in `rem`?

Comment: The idea behind flexbox grid is the same as Bootstrap, the grid is conformed of 12 columns. `col-sm-1`  represents `1/12` of the total width of the container. The container has a fixed width applied in media queries just to be able to center the content with `margin-left` and `margin-right` `auto`. If the container's `width` is `1000px`, `col-sm-1` will take 8.34%~ of that value. 83.34px~.. `rem` units just take the value of `font-size` from the `html`.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz so far so good, does that mean that in order to get 8.34% of the container width which is defined in the media query, the col-sm-1 has to be defined within the same media query. what would happen if i set the container width within the media query but did not define the col-sm-1 within the media query. would it still be able to pick up the container width correctly? or am i just overthinking this?

Comment: It would, but the idea of having `sm` viewport is for those rules to only apply on certain devices, not the ones that correspond to `xs`. Not including the `sm` classes inside a media query would not follow the logic behind the framework.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz, it is a convention, then. I understand that it enables me to specify classes like `col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-3` . They want to ensure that the css for `col-sm-3` can only be used within the correct viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The css wrapped in media queries so that you will have a different behavior for every screen resolution. This is the hole essence of responsive design.

The xs classes are not wrapped in media queries because they're style will apply for all the screen widths unless there arent any other sizes tags (sm,md,lg).